# How to cut every nth line of file A while read value from file B?

Tags: while-loop, cut

I would like to cut every nth line in file A by the value of file B, line by line.

File A looks like:

```
@V300059044L3C001R0010004402
AAGTAGATATCATGGAGCCGTTG
+
FGFFGFFGFFGGGGGFFFGGFGF
@V300059044L3C001R0010009240
AAAGGGAGGGAGAATAATGG
+
FGEFDFGGEFFGGEDEGEGF
...
```

File B looks like:

```
12
5
4
19
...
```

I want to cut the fourth line from file A with the first value of file b, the 8th line with the 2nd value of file b and so on.

I am using the command below which cuts line 1, 2, 3, ... instead of 4, 8, 12.

```
for i in *fileA; do fileB=${i/A/B}; while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -ru3 b; do printf %s\\n "${b:a}" & [ $( jobs | wc -l ) -ge $( sysctl -n hw.ncpu ) ] && wait; done <$i 3< $fileB > output; done
```

I used the last part to hurry up the command `& [ $( jobs | wc -l ) -ge $( sysctl -n hw.ncpu ) ] && wait` (it takes a few hours ...)

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux distribution does not install Ed by default, then you will want to do that for this script.  It's a very small program, so there's no reason not to have it.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

cp file-a.txt stack

next () {
[ -s stack ] && main
end
}

main() {
ed -s stack < file-a.ed
ed -s 4lines.txt < 4lines.ed
next
}

end() {
paste new-a.txt file-b.txt > merged-file.txt
rm -v ./*.ed
rm -v ./4lines.txt
rm -v ./stack
rm -v ./new-a.txt
exit 0
}

cat >> file-a.ed << EOF
1,4W 4lines.txt
1,4d
wq
EOF

cat >> 4lines.ed << EOF
1,3d
1W new-a.txt
1d
wq
EOF

next
```